# "argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kde4, pykde

I'm trying to use PyKDE, `PyKDE.kdecore.KStandardDirs` to be precise. This method is called with two strings according to the [documentation](http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.3-api/kdecore/KStandardDirs.html) and according to the PyQt4 documentation, I can use standard Python `str`s instead of `QString`.
This doesn't work:

```
>> KStandardDirs.locate()("socket", "foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: KStandardDirs.locate(): not enough arguments
>>> KStandardDirs.locate("socket", "foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: KStandardDirs.locate(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I can't use `QString` either because it doesn't seem to exist:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QString
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> QString
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QString' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that PyKDE is not yet Python 3 ready, at least as far as that error message is concerned; try passing in a bytestring instead:

```
KStandardDirs.locate(b"socket", "foo")
```

Comment: That's it, though the second argument has to be a regular string: `KStandardDirs.locate(b"socket", "foo")`

Comment: @Erik: cool, glad that worked. Updated the answer to reflect better what I think is going on.